# How to fix "/tmp is not ready or not present" after dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, tmp

How can I fix "/tmp is not ready or not present" on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: did you able to get into Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `/tmp` directory inside your `/` folder. For this, you have to boot from Ubuntu live disk.

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk.
- Get the `root` partition name.(Name of the partition where Ubuntu is installed. It will be like `/dev/sdXx`)
- Now mount that partition on `/mnt`,

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdXx /mnt
  ```
- Create a tmp directory inside  `/mnt`.

  ```
  sudo mkdir /mnt/tmp
  ```
- Now change the permissions.

  ```
  sudo chmod 1777 /mnt/tmp
  ```
- Unmount the mounted partition.

  ```
  sudo umount /dev/sdXx
  ```
- Reboot your pc.